# Base class not recognized

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I just added [MASPreferences](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASPreferences) to my project. It's a small library to help creating preference windows. Since it's just one class and a .xib I simply added them to my main target. When I try to use them, I get errors that basically mean that the class was not found (when I want to subclass it, or alloc an instance I get errors). Any ideas why I could be missing?

The .m file and the .xib are added to the target.
The .h file are in a folder that is in the Header Search Paths (../Libraries/**)
Since it's not an ARC class, I added the -fno-objc-arc flag to the .m file.
The .h file is of course imported where I use them.

These are the errors:

```
_pref = [[MASPreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithViewControllers:ctrls
                                                                  title:title];
// Use of undeclared identifier 'MASPreferencesWindowController'.
```

```
@interface SBPreferencesWindowController : MASPreferencesWindowController
// Class 'SBPreferencesWindowController' defined without specifying a base class
```

MASPreferencesWindowController.h is imported in both cases.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `MASPreferencesWindowController` and not `MASPreferencesViewController` which is a protocol?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes. I'm able to use the protocol and create a class that implements it. But I get error messages when I try to use the `MASPreferencesWindowController` class. I added two examples to my question.

Comment: Go to Project Settings Build Phases (Target)see if you can find the .m file in Compile Sources. if it's not here add it.

Comment: Are there any other libraries in *Header Search Paths* that **do** work?  I would suspect that setting.

Comment: @Radu It's there. I also added the -fno-obj-arc flag to that .m file.

Comment: @trojanfoe, There are other libraries there that work. Both simple ones that I directly include in the main target and more complex ones that compile as a separate library/target. I just tried to include the library in a clean template project (just drop them into the project) and I have the same issue.

Comment: So are you actually compiling those files as a separate project?  Why not simply include them in the project that is using them and then there is no need for *Header/Library Search Paths* at all.

Comment: i am out of ideas have you taken a look at MASPreferencesDemo - https://github.com/shpakovski/MASPreferencesDemo maybe you can find the solution there

Comment: @trojanfoe No, they are not in a separate project or target. They are actually part of the main target. I just wanted to mention that they are also in a folder that is in the Header Search Path, because I'm trying everything I can think of.

Comment: And you definitely added the `.h` files to the project?  If you have and it still doesn't work then something is wrong.  I would also suggest that you don't put them in the "search paths" folders as that makes no sense; just include them in the project as if you had written them yourself.

Comment: @Radu I am looking at the demo right now. The main difference I can see, is that it doesn't use ARC. But don't know why that would have any influence on class *visibility*.

Comment: I just restarted Xcode and and now it works. Could be a bug in Xcode 5.

Comment: You shouldn't be discussing Xcode 5 on SO, as it's under NDA.  It's bound to have bugs as it's pre-release software.

Comment: X Code has some problems with detecting project settings changes in some cases - i think a clean target and build would have worked to. good to know for future projects.

Comment: I cleaned the project multiple times. I'm aware of this problem and I actually have a shortcut that deletes the complete build folder, because I don't trust Xcodes clean command :)